# Why am I unable to filter my JSON array in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, filter

Working in d3.js, my data is something like this (but much longer):

```
var all = [{
"tp_ot_avg": 0.003,
"tp_ot_s": 24.7,
"tp_overlap_pc_s": 45.7,
"tp_ot_avg_s": 0.005,
"sw_adult": 74,
"sw_overlap": 6,
"sw_child": 7,
"sw_pause": 13
}];
```

I want to filter it by key name; the desired output is this:

```
var data = {
"sw_adult": 74,
"sw_overlap": 6,
"sw_child": 7,
"sw_pause": 13
};
```

So far, nothing I've tried has worked!

ATTEMPT 1:

```
var data = all.filter(function (a) {
  return (
    a.key == "sw_adult" ||
    a.key == "sw_child" ||
    a.key == "sw_overlap" ||
    a.key == "sw_pause"
  );
});
```

ATTEMPT 2:

```
tokeep = ["sw_adult", "sw_child", "sw_overlap", "sw_pause"]
var data = all.filter(function(d,i){ return tokeep.indexOf(d.key) >= 0 })
```

ATTEMPT 3:

```
var data = d3.selectAll("all").filter(
    all.key == "sw_adult" ||
    all.key == "sw_child" ||
    all.key == "sw_overlap" ||
    all.key == "sw_pause"
  );
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your all array contain's only one object then you can use simply do this way.

```js
const keys = ["sw_adult", "sw_overlap", "sw_child", "sw_pause"];
const all = [{
  "tp_ot_avg": 0.003,
  "tp_ot_s": 24.7,
  "tp_overlap_pc_s": 45.7,
  "tp_ot_avg_s": 0.005,
  "sw_adult": 74,
  "sw_overlap": 6,
  "sw_child": 7,
  "sw_pause": 13
}];

const output = Object.keys(all[0]).reduce((result, current) => {
  if (keys.includes(current)) {
    result[current] = all[0][current];
  }
  return result;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

And It's any chance that all array can have multiple object then you can do this way.

```js
const keys = ["sw_adult", "sw_overlap", "sw_child", "sw_pause"];
const all = [{
  "tp_ot_avg": 0.003,
  "tp_ot_s": 24.7,
  "tp_overlap_pc_s": 45.7,
  "tp_ot_avg_s": 0.005,
  "sw_adult": 74,
  "sw_overlap": 6,
  "sw_child": 7,
  "sw_pause": 13
}, {
  "tp_ot_avg": 0.003,
  "tp_ot_s": 24.7,
  "tp_overlap_pc_s": 45.7,
  "tp_ot_avg_s": 0.005,
  "sw_adult": 742,
  "sw_overlap": 62,
  "sw_child": 72,
  "sw_pause": 132
}];

const output = all.map((a) => Object.keys(a).reduce((result, current) => {
  if (keys.includes(current)) {
    result[current] = a[current];
  }
  return result;
}, {}));
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You were in the right direction, just [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the keys that you need.

Iterate through the `all` array, in every iteration check for its entries using [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) whether the current object [`has the keys or not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), if it has extract it using [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) and break the flow once you found your desired object.

```js
var all = [{
    "tp_ot_avg": 0.003,
    "tp_ot_s": 24.7,
    "tp_overlap_pc_s": 45.7,
    "tp_ot_avg_s": 0.005,
    "sw_adult": 74,
    "sw_overlap": 6,
    "sw_child": 7,
    "sw_pause": 13
  },
  {
    "tp_ot_avg": 0.003,
    "tp_ot_s": 24.7,
    "tp_overlap_pc_s": 45.7,
    "tp_ot_avg_s": 0.005
  }
];

const keys = ['sw_adult', 'sw_overlap', 'sw_child', 'sw_pause'];
let resObj;

for (const item of all) {
  const filteredEntries = Object.entries(item).filter(([key, value]) => keys.includes(key));
  if (filteredEntries.length) {
    resObj = Object.fromEntries(filteredEntries);
    break;
  }
}

console.log(resObj);
```

Comment: This is so helpful, thank you! It's still not working quite right for me - I think because I was trying to get an object ({...}), and I believe this returns an array([...])? Do you know how I would get this data as an object?

Answer (score 0):

The attempts made are to filter the array object, not the object keys. Try:

```js
var all = [{
  "tp_ot_avg": 0.003,
  "tp_ot_s": 24.7,
  "tp_overlap_pc_s": 45.7,
  "tp_ot_avg_s": 0.005,
  "sw_adult": 74,
  "sw_overlap": 6,
  "sw_child": 7,
  "sw_pause": 13
}];


// destruct the properties and return a new object
const output = all.map(({
  sw_adult,
  sw_child,
  sw_overlap,
  sw_pause
}) => ({
  sw_adult,
  sw_child,
  sw_overlap,
  sw_pause
}))

// Shorter and uses a list of keys to pick
const keys = ["sw_adult","sw_overlap","sw_child","sw_pause"];
// return a new object from merging objects created by { key: value }
const output2 = all.map(o =>
   Object.assign({}, ...keys.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })))
);

console.log(output2);
```

Comment: Thank you for this! It's still not working quite right for me - I think because I was trying to get an object ({...}), and I believe this returns an array([...])? Do you know how I would get this data as an object?